# Save persistent data in onPause() or onStop()?

Tags: android

Is is true that when your application needs to save some persistent data you should always do it in `onPause()` method in addition to the `onStop()` method, because if android OS kills your process then `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` methods are never called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is is true that when your application needs to save some persistent data you should always do it in onPause() method in addition to the onStop() method

**SHORT ANSWER :** TRUE , `onPause()` is even more reliable than `onStop()`. And the chances of killing the process without invoking `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are the highest.

**WHY ?**

The Activity life cycle diagram is the best aid in this scenario:

[image]

You can clearly see the order in which the methods are invoked. The safest choice as you can see is the `onPause()`, which provides the first indication that the user is leaving your Activity, and then comes the `onStop()` which indicates the app has entered to the Stopped state . And finally comes the `onDestroy()` method. So it's safest to choose `onPause()` to save the persistent data at the earliest.

**FURTHERMORE :**
The chance and correlation between Activity states and ejection is clearly provided in this table :  [Activity state and ejection from memory](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem)

Comment: See, that's what I thought. Saving data in `onPause()` and `onStop()` catches all possible use cases. Sure, maybe `onPause()` is the "safest" but I want the app to be foolproof, not just safe.

Comment: In what situation would the app skip onPause() and go straight to onStop()?

Answer (score 2):

You should save any critical data in `onPause` because it is always called when your activity loses focus or user is exiting the app. On the other hand, `onStop` is only called when the user is exiting the app, but not when they switch to a different activity(loses focus). Also, when your activity is in the background, android will forcefully kill your app process on low memory in which case `onStop` will not be called, `onDestroy` is called. So, `onPause` is where you should run your persistence code, no need to do it in `onStop`

Comment: on pause is the only guaranted place.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda My answer is the verbose version of your comment

Comment: Looking at the life cycle diagram, there seems to be a use case where the app is killed without `onPause()` being called.

Comment: @the_prole what? `onPause` is **always** called. The diagram clearly shows that too